# React Native: Unable to center Text in View component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text-alignment, react-native-stylesheet

I am unable to **center** a `Text` component in a `View` component in React Native both on **android** as well as **ios**.

As you can see the **+** sign in not centred in the **white circle**.

[image]

This is my component:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.blueButton}
>
    <View style={styles.addButton}>
        <Text style={styles.plus}>+</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is my stylesheet:

```
blueButton: {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    borderRadius: 3,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#3498DB',
},
addButton: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
},
plus: {
    color: '#3498DB',
    fontSize: 20,
},
```

Comment: Can you show your View with blue color as in the screenshot also its design ?

Comment: Sure, I've added the blue button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try my below code:

Compnent code:

```
<View style={styles.addButtonBlue}>
  <View style={styles.addButton}>
    <Text style={styles.plus}>+</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Stylesheet Code

```
addButtonBlue: {
  width: 70,
  height: 70,
  borderRadius: 10,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#3498db',
},
addButton: {
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  borderRadius: 30,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
plus: {
    color: '#3498DB',
},
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, your solution doesn't work with `addButton` having dimensions of 15px.

Comment: Let me check..Can you show your View with blue color as in the screenshot also its design ?

Comment: Sure, I've added the blue button as well.

Comment: But it does work for me when I change addButton  width and Height to 15,  Anyway you update your question, I ll check

Comment: @VinaySharma It is working for me brother.. You still face issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208023/discussion-between-vinay-sharma-and-ajith).

Answer (score 0):

The extra font padding in android might be the culprit here. Try adding `includeFontPadding: false` to the text style.

more info here - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#style

> includeFontPadding: bool (Android)
>
> Set to false to remove extra font padding intended to make space for
> certain ascenders / descenders. With some fonts, this padding can make
> text look slightly misaligned when centered vertically. For best
> results also set textAlignVertical to center. Default is true.